# Is $W=\{(x, y, z, w)^T : x+2y-3z+w=2\}$ a vector subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

$W=\{(x, y, z, w)^T : x+2y-3z+w=2\}$

No idea how to deal with the transpose or how to prove whether this is or isn't a subspace of a vector space..

Comment: Does it contain the zero vector?

Comment: I guess not since 0 does not equal 2.. but what if it was equal to 0 instead of 2? How would I solve it then?

Comment: @user103068 The condition $0\in W$ is *necessary* for $W$ being a subspace. There are other two conditions: “if $x,y\in W$ then $x+y\in W$” and “if $x\in W$ and $\alpha$ is a scalar, then $\alpha x\in W$”. A counterexample to any of the three conditions shows $W$ is not a subspace. Exercise: if instead of $2$ you have $0$, then $W$ would indeed be a subspace.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Does it pass the Subspace Test? that is, does it/is it

$a)$ contain the zero vector? (i.e, is $\vec{0}\in W)$?

$b)$ closed under scalar multiplication? (i.e, if $X\in W$, then $aX\in W, \forall a\in\mathbb{R}$ )

$c)$ closed under addition? (i.e, if $X,Y\in W$, then $X+Y\in\ W$)